# Where does Odoo product.product taxes_id come from?

Tags: odoo-8

I'll like to understand where `product.obj.taxes_id` at `https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/sale/sale.py#L1152` come from. I can't find any reference to it in `product.product` or `sale.order.line` or `product.template`.

Not sure if I'm missing something. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Many2many relation. [see for reference](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account/product.py#L46)